# EMMS is not displaying tag info with libtag

Tags: emms

EMMS seems to be completely unaware of any tag / metadata in my music files.  I tried configuring it with mp3info (I no longer want this anyway), and now with libtag, checking that they work in command line, and I have deleted and recreated the cache at "~/.emacs.d/emms/cache" to no avail.  The emms-browser categorises everything as misc and seems to know nothing more than the file names.

I'll detail my configuration.

My init.el has

```
;;emms configuration
(require 'emms)
(require 'emms-setup)
(emms-all)
(emms-default-players)
(setq emms-source-file-default-directory "/Volumes/Seabeam HD/Music/")
(require 'emms-info-libtag)
(setq emms-info-functions '(emms-info-libtag))
(autoload 'emms-smart-browse "emms-browser.el" "Browse with EMMS" t)
(global-set-key [(f7)] 'emms-smart-browse)
```

and I installed emms from elpa.  I also cloned the emms git repo and did

```
make emms-print-metadata
```

and put the binary in my path and tested it  (I also did `sudo make install` from here, and hopefully did not mess things up now that I'm running off the elpa version).  It prints id3 tags and other metadata as expected.  In installed `mp3info` from macports and tested that too.  Reads id3v1 tags, as expected.

Now, I'm using GUI Emacs.app, so I have `exec-path-from-shell` to ensure that emacs finds commands it needs.

EMMS makes a directory, "~/.emacs.d/emms/" where it stores history, cache, etc.  I deleted this after setting things up for libtag and have also restarted emacs.

I've read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emms/manual/#Using-TagLib) and this other [emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/what-are-the-options-to-play-music-from-within-emacs) on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by removing `~/.emacs.d/elpa/emms-*` and `~/.emacs.d/elpa/emms` and installing from the git repo instead of elpa.  I don't know why the method in my original question didn't work but here is a tutorial for how I got the metadata to work.  It basically follows instructions from the [Manual's Quickstart Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/manual/#Quickstart-Guide).

With the same contents of init.el I did `git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/emms.git` in `~/.emacs.d/lisp/` and ran `make` and `sudo make install`.  Previously I had compiled and put the binary for `emms-print-metadata` in my executable path variable, and ensured that emacs knows about the same path variable.  I also installed mplayer to play files.

Since this is not an elpa package I had to tell emacs where to find it by adding  `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/emms/lisp/")` to my init file.  I'll repeat the other part of the configuration with comments to help the next person:

```
;;emms configuration ;;; elisp comment ;)
(require 'emms)      ;;; load emms from "~/.emacs.d/lisp/emms/lisp/"
                     ;;; i.e., the core functionality
(require 'emms-setup);;; load some functions that will set some preferences
                     ;;; it's worth looking at this file
(emms-all)           ;;; load all stable features of emms, defined in emms-setup
(emms-default-players);; load a list of default players (like mplayer) installed defined in emms-setup
(setq emms-source-file-default-directory "/Volumes/Seabeam HD/Music/")
(require 'emms-info-libtag) ;;; load functions that will talk to emms-print-metadata which in turn talks to libtag and gets metadata
(setq emms-info-functions '(emms-info-libtag)) ;;; make sure libtag is the only thing delivering metadata
;;; below is a nice key command for toggling the music browser
(autoload 'emms-smart-browse "emms-browser.el" "Browse with EMMS" t)
(global-set-key [(f7)] 'emms-smart-browse)
```

I then reloaded init.el / restarted emacs and did `M-x emms-add-directory-tree RET RET` (I didn't need to change the default because of emms-source-file-default-directory).  I waited a while and emms playlist buffer started updating tracks as it found the metadata.  Finally I opened emms-browser (f7) and could browse by artist, album, title, etc, and my metadata was all there.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: This answer did help me with a related problem! But could you fix the quote mark `'` in the `~/.emacs.d/lisp/'` line in the answer, so that the formatting is applied properly? I'd do it myself but I can't make a change of fewer than 6 characters.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. My hypothesis is that the `emms-print-metadata` binary has to exist at the time emms is installed for it to work. So the active ingredient in your solution, I suspect, is that the binary was present when you installed emms for the second time, not that you installed it from the git repository. At least in my case, I reinstalled following the same installation method and the problem was also fixed. (I mention this in case it helps others also facing this issue.)