# Unable to let emms understand metadata

Tags: emms

I don't understand why all my music artist/genre/album *etc.* are classified under misc/unknown given the fact that I'm confident that 90% of 200G music do have metadata. I managed to get the source of `emms-print-metadata` and installed it, tested it on an `mp3` and it does return a result. I have the following configuration. There is nothing special: I just followed the documentation and tweaked a bit to use `mpv` as default player.

```lisp
(use-package emms
  :ensure t
  :requires (emms-setup emms-player-mpv)
  :config
  (emms-all)
  (setq emms-player-list '(emms-player-mpv)
    emms-browser-covers 'emms-browser-cache-thumbnail-async
    emms-source-file-default-directory "~/Music/"
    emms-info-functions '(emms-info-libtag)
    emms-player-mpv-parameters '("--really-quiet" "--no-video"))

  (when (executable-find "emms-print-metadata")
    (require 'emms-info-libtag)
    (add-to-list 'emms-info-functions 'emms-info-libtag)))
```

**Question.** How to let `emms` understand metadata and display them correctly in `emms-browser-search-by-*` buffers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the cache `M-x emms-cache-reset` and then re-importing your music `M-x emms-add-directory-tree`.  Then `emms-info-libtag` will cook away in the background for a bit and, after a few minutes, you should see your metadata.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly, this should be written in the documentation. I followed the path of [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22424/emms-is-not-displaying-tag-info-with-libtag) but it seems that it was not enough.